# Python script to save email in a physical folder

Tags: python, outlook, office365

I am a first time user of stack overflow. I am reaching out here because I have trouble saving outlook email (.MSG) using python. The idea is to archive email as it is in physical drive.

Everything works, except the save As command which throw a very generic error. It would be great help if anyone can help me please.

Here is the code I am I Using:

```
import win32com.client as win32
from win32com.client import Dispatch
import os
import re

os.chdir("C:\\Users\\username\\Downloads\\RPA")

outlook = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
inbox = outlook.GetDefaultFolder(6)
print(inbox)
messages = inbox.Items
for message in messages:
    message = messages.GetNext()
    name = str(message.Subject)
    name = re.sub('[^A-Za-z0-9]+', '', name) + '.msg'
    print(name)
    # message.Display(True)
    message.SaveAs(os.getcwd() + '//' + name)
```

> The Error I get executing the code
>
> ```
>     return self._oleobj_.InvokeTypes(61521, LCID, 1, (24, 0), ((8, 1), (12, 17)),Path
>     pywintypes.com_error: (-2147467260, 'Operation aborted', None, None)
> ```

Answer (score 1):

In the code you are iterating over all items in the Inbox folder:

```
for message in messages:
    message = messages.GetNext()
    name = str(message.Subject)
    name = re.sub('[^A-Za-z0-9]+', '', name) + '.msg'
```

If the folder contains a lot of items the operation may take some time to complete. I'd suggest processing items in chunks, so you may keep Outlook under control and prevent freezing the UI (if any). The `Find`/`FindNext` or `Restrict` methods can help with that. Read more about these methods in the following articles:

- [How To: Use Find and FindNext methods to retrieve Outlook mail items from a folder (C#, VB.NET)](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/20/outlook-find-findnext-retrieve-mail/)
- [How To: Use Restrict method to retrieve Outlook mail items from a folder](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/23/outlook-restrict-method-retrieve-mail/)

Another point is that a file name should be unique for all items in the folder. What is the actual string argument passed to the `SaveAs` method?

Also you need to make sure that no forbidden symbols are used in the filename.

Comment: Thanks for response. I will try them let you know if it worked